# MySQL 5.6 Aborted_connects increase without error log

Tags: mysql

- MySQL server version: 5.6.26
- Linux: Linux 2.6.32-431.11.7.el6.ucloud.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 7 23:42:27 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Situation:

  - Aborted_connects increase 5-10 every minutes
  - log_warnings=2, but no error/warnings in error files
  - using TCPDUMP 3306 port, but cannot find any aborted connection request.

server status like below:

```
# Variable_name, Value
Aborted_connects, 7991
Connection_errors_accept, 0
Connection_errors_internal, 0
Connection_errors_max_connections, 0
Connection_errors_peer_address, 3
Connection_errors_select, 0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap, 0
Connections, 8051
Max_used_connections, 24
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost, 0
Ssl_client_connects, 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates, 0
Ssl_finished_connects, 0
Threads_connected, 22
```

some referred server variables like below:

```
connect_timeout 10
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_connect_errors  100
table_open_cache    2000
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  3
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
```

at least the reason was a ZABBIX setting for mysql template wrong.
Does somebody know why the ZABBIX_AGENT of current server connect error were not be writed in the error log of mysql when log_warning level is 2?

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/08/23/how-to-track-down-the-source-of-aborted_connects/ shows a case when this counter is incremented on connection attempts with bad credentials.

Comment: @jkavalik had try, but nothing in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Zabbix_Agent process connect to mysql server.
I cannot understand, why the log_warnings=2 cannot log the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`Aborted_connects/Connections` is nearly 1.  This is extremely high.

`Threads_connected` is always 1 or more because "1" is the connection that is doing the `SHOW STATUS`.  `Max_used_connections = 2` probably does mean that two connections were connected at some time.  It is a high-water-mark.